# jQuery Ajax Get Request trouble

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am new to Ajax requests.  I am using the StackExchange api "search" to do a get request and return each() "score" to the Chrome Dev Tool's console.

Head over here to see the jSON.

```
 http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?page=1&pagesize=5&order=desc&sort=activity&title=C%23&site=stackoverflow
```

Here is what I got so far:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?page=1&pagesize=5&order=desc&sort=activity&title=C%23&site=stackoverflow',
    success: function(items){
        $.each(items, function(index, object){
             console.log(object.score);
         });
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you just missed one little thing.

See JSON from your link.

```
{
    items: [...],
    has_more: true,
    ...
}
```

You should use

```
$.each(items.items, ...
```

in your code. Success function here wraps up the full JSON data. You'd better user 'data' as parameter name to avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: Like this?  
        success: function(data){
        $.each(data.items, function(index, object){
             console.log(object.score);
         });